# Hanner's Inequality to prove weak convergence and convergence of norms implies strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I am working on a homework question that has given me some difficulty.

**The Question**

Let $1<p\le2$ and let $f,g\in L^p(\Omega)$. Use Hanner's inequality,

$$2^p\left(||f||_p^p + ||g||^p_p\right)\ge(||f+g||_p+||f-g||_p)^p + \bigg|||f+g||_p-||f-g||_p\bigg|^p$$

to show that if $f_n$ weakly converges to $f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, and $||f_n||_p \to ||f||_p$, then $||f_n-f||_p \to 0$.

**My Work**

I am aware that Hanner's inequality implies uniform convexity which implies the desired result. However the proofs I have seen that uniform convexity are very long and I don't imagine this is the scope of the question.

I tried substituting $g = f_n$ into Hanner, throwing away the second term on the left hand side and taking limits on both sides, however I am not sure the limit even exists on the left hand side.

Comment: You say "weak convergence and norm convergence implies strong convergence" in the title, but I usually "norm convergence" to mean the same thing as "strong convergence". The body of the question refers to no such additional assumption, but an additional assumption is definitely necessary. Did you mean, perhaps, $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$?

Comment: Oops. Sorry, yes I did. I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Hanner's inequality to $g=f_n$ for a fixed $n$ then take $\limsup_{n\to +\infty}$ to get (in view of the assumption of convergence of the norms)
$$\tag{*}
2^{p+1}\lVert f\rVert_p^p\geqslant \limsup_{n\to +\infty}\left(\left(a_n+b_n\right)^p+\left\lvert a_n-b_n\right\rvert^p\right)
$$
where $a_n=\lVert f+f_n\rVert_p$ and $b_n=\lVert f_n-f\rVert_p$. Note that sequence $(b_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded; let $B:=\limsup_{n\to +\infty}b_n$ and $n_k\uparrow +\infty$ such that $b_{n_k}\to B$. Then by (*) and the weak convergence of $f+f_{n_k}$ to $2f$, we derive that
$$
2^{p+1}\lVert f\rVert_p^p\geqslant\left(\left(2\lVert f\rVert_p+B\right)^p+\left\lvert 2\lVert f\rVert_p-B\right\rvert^p\right).
$$
Using the fact that the function $t\mapsto \left(2\lVert f\rVert_p+t\right)^p+\left\lvert 2\lVert f\rVert_p-t\right\rvert^p$ reaches its unique minimum at $t_0=  0$, we derive that the only possibility is $B=0$.

Comment: How doews $f_{n_k}$ converges weakly to $f$ and $||f_{n_k}||_p \to ||f||_p$ give us that $||f_{n_k} + f||_p \to ||2f||_p$? I must be missing something really simple here.

Comment: At this point, we do not know yet that $f_{n_k}+f$ converges strongly to $2f$. However, we know that $2\lVert  f\rVert_p\leqslant\liminf_{k\to +\infty}\lVert f_{n_k}-f\rVert_p$.

Comment: Assuming you meant $2||f||_p \le \liminf_{k\to \infty} ||f_{n_k} + f||_p$, that makes sense to me. Thanks a lot for your help. Just out of curiosity, how long did this take you to figure out? I'm assuming you've been in math for a while. Are statements like these immediate to you?

Comment: Yes I  meant $f_{n_k}+f$. No this was not immediate; the idea of taking $g=f_n$ came quite quickly, but after I had to check that really works.

Comment: One more thing, the function you define at the end, I believe attains its minimum at $t_0 = 0$. The argument you provide still works I believe.

Comment: @epsilon You are right.